# How can i remove blank nested form field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i reject the blank nested field in nested form in rails i am using this code:

```
class Award < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category, :country_iso,:title, :year,:status ,:nomination_awards_attributes,:sponsor_awards_attributes,:city
  has_many :nomination_awards, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sponsor_awards, dependent: :destroy


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :nomination_awards, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sponsor_awards, :allow_destroy => true#,:reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:sponsor_id].blank? }
  validates :title,:category,:country_iso,:year,:city, :presence => true


end
```

Comment: please refer this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653511/accepts-nested-attributes-for-reject-if-how-to-prevent-rejection-until-paren

Comment: thanks for this but i need to remove the blank fields not first ????

Answer (score 0):

reject the blank field using this code 
:reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:sponsor_id].blank? }

and check in in edit data is present or not, if data is present or build we no need to build in edit page if not present or build we have to build it on edit page ....